# Alterar a cor do background quando a ListView não tem itens

Tags: android

Existe alguma forma de customizar uma `listView` além do `textView`  padrão? A tela fica vazia obviamente, mas gostaria de alterar a cor do background apenas quando a buscar não exibir os resultados.

```
 mEstadoVazioTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.visualizacaoVazia);
        listview.setEmptyView(mEstadoVazioTextView);

 mEstadoVazioTextView.setText("Nenhum livro encontrado!\n\nFavor verificar ortografia ou" +
                    " informar algum dado sobre o livro novamente.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de disponibilizar a lista ao *Adapter* verifique se ela está vazia e altere o *background* da ListView em conformidade.

Qualquer coisa assim:

```
if(lista.size() == 0){
    listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
else{
    listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
}
```

**Edit após o comentário**

> estou usando Loader, o carregamento da lista é fora do onCreate, como referencio a variavel nesse caso?

Declare a variável, para guardar a ListView, como atributo da Activity.

```
private ListView listview;
```

No método `onLoadFinished()` verifique se o cursor tem resultados e altere o *background* da ListView em conformidade:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    else{
        listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    }

    adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
}
```

Comment: estou usando Loader, o carregamento da lista é fora do onCreate, como referencio a variavel nesse caso?

Comment: Editei a resposta. Ela responde à sua dúvida?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, olha tbm sou novato em desenvolvimento, mas espero conseguir ajudar.

Pelo que eu entendi você possui uma ListView que esta sendo populada com uma lista de Livros, o que você quer é se a busca não retornar resultado que seja exibida uma mensagem ao usuário.

Eu já fiz isso de algumas formas diferentes.

**1)** Ao invés de colocar a mensagem na ListView, você poderia pegar o tamanho da lista e se essa lista possuir tamanho 0 (não havendo resultado listado) você pode colocar essa mensagem no Layout (não na ListView).

```
int tamanho = Lista.size();
if(tamanho == 0){
    Texto.SetText("Livro não encontrado")
}
```

**2)** Agora se você quer realmente customizar a Lista, aconselho que utilize um RecyclerView pois, terá mais liberdade na customização. Pesquise sobre isso que certamente ajudará.

**3)** Você ainda pode colocar um Toast informando o usuário que não há resultado na pesquisa.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: oi, obrigada pela ajuda, mas a mensagem já está sendo apresentada caso não retorne nenhum resultado, gostaria mesmo era de customizar  o layout qndo ele retorna nesse estado, estou usando a mensagem no `listView`, pois o método `setEmptyView()` já cuida dessa parte do resultado da busca por vazio.

Comment: Blz! Então pesquise sobre RecyclerView que você terá o que procura. Tem muitos vídeos explicando passo a passo a implementação. Explicando por aqui ficaria muito grande o post. Boa Sorte!